# Powershell Wait for service to be stopped or started

Tags: powershell

I have searched both this forum and through google and can't find what I need.
I have a quite large script and I'm looking for some code that will check if the service is started or stopped before proceeding to the next step.

The function it self need to loop untill it's either stopped or started (Going to have a function for Stopped and one for Started).

In total 4 services which almost have the same name, so Service Bus * can be used as a wildcard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following will loop and verify the status of the given services until the number of services with the "Running" state is equal to zero (hence they are stopped), so you can use this if you are waiting for services to Stop.

I've added a `$MaxRepeat` variable, which will prevent this from running for ever. It will run 20 times max as defined.

```
$services = "Service Bus *"
$maxRepeat = 20
$status = "Running" # change to Stopped if you want to wait for services to start

do 
{
    $count = (Get-Service $services | ? {$_.status -eq $status}).count
    $maxRepeat--
    sleep -Milliseconds 600
} until ($count -eq 0 -or $maxRepeat -eq 0)
```

Comment: I'm not stopping or starting any service manually. It'ts commands preivously in the script that will stop and start services. I just want to see that the service is started or stopped so the script can proceed, the function should no try to start or stop a service.

Comment: This is what this loop does. It just checks for the status of the given services. I clarified in the answer

Comment: Seems to work. When running some commands related to service bus, it gives output in a grey field over the console window like "Stopping Farm" etc. These does not release untill script is done and block some of the output. Is there any way to make sure they go away once they are done. Else it's all working like a charm.

Comment: With a little modification, this works perfectly for the need. The `WaitForStatus` simply won't suffice if you want to make sure that the service is stopped or running before moving forward with your script.

Comment: Consider changing the preferred solution to another of the answers that doesn't waste CPU cycles like this.

Answer (score 58):

I couldn't get the 'count' strategy, that Micky posted, to work, so here is how i solved it:

I created a function, that takes a searchString (this could be "Service Bus *") and the status that i expect the services should reach.

```
function WaitUntilServices($searchString, $status)
{
    # Get all services where DisplayName matches $searchString and loop through each of them.
    foreach($service in (Get-Service -DisplayName $searchString))
    {
        # Wait for the service to reach the $status or a maximum of 30 seconds
        $service.WaitForStatus($status, '00:00:30')
    }
}
```

The function can now be called with

```
WaitUntilServices "Service Bus *" "Stopped"
```

or

```
WaitUntilServices "Service Bus *" "Running"
```

If the timeout period is reached, a not so graceful exception is thrown:

```
Exception calling "WaitForStatus" with "2" argument(s): "Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed."
```

Comment: The best answer, as of now, for the situation and a lot more cleaner to understand.

Answer (score 37):

In addition to the [answer of mgarde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355759/1811525) this one liner might be useful if you just want to wait for a single service (also inspired by a [post from Shay Levy](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/10/pstip-wait-for-a-service-to-reach-a-specified-status/)):

```
(Get-Service SomeInterestingService).WaitForStatus('Running')
```

Comment: I learned from Shay Levy's post that you also have the option to add a TimeSpan for the status to wait: (Get-Service SomeInterestingService).WaitForStatus('Running', ,'00:00:10')

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak this a bit with multiple counters because this service purposely starts and stops slowly. The original script got me on the right track.  I had to wait for the service to be in a completely stopped status before I could move on because I'm actually restarting that same service. 
You could probably remove the "sleep," but I don't mind leaving it in.
You could probably remove everything and just use the $stopped variable. :)

```
    # change to Stopped if you want to wait for services to start
    $running = "Running" 
    $stopPending = "StopPending"
    $stopped = "Stopped"
    do 
    {
        $count1 = (Get-Service $service | ? {$_.status -eq $running}).count
        sleep -Milliseconds 600
        $count2 = (Get-Service $service | ? {$_.status -eq $stopPending}).count
        sleep -Milliseconds 600
        $count3 = (Get-Service $service | ? {$_.status -eq $stopped}).count
        sleep -Milliseconds 600
    } until ($count1 -eq 0 -and $count2 -eq 0 -and $count3 -eq 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Azure build/deployment pipelines I use it like this to start and stop services (after already having sent a 'Stop' command asynchronously before) and which works for all transitional states like `Starting`, `Stopping`, `Pausing` and `Resuming` (which are called `StartPending`, `StopPending`, `PausePending` and `ContinuePending` in the status enumeration [`ServiceControllerStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)).

```
# Wait for services to be stopped or stop them
$ServicesToStop | ForEach-Object {
  $MyService = Get-Service -Name $_ -ComputerName $Server;
  while ($MyService.Status.ToString().EndsWith('Pending')) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
    $MyService.Refresh();
  };
  $MyService | Stop-Service -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue;
  $MyService.Dispose();
};
```

This needs a traditional powershell to function on a remote server, the cmdlet of `pwsh.exe` does not include parameter `-ComputerName`.

In my opinion no counters are needed as only transitional states cause the cmdlet to fail and they change anyway to one of the supported states in the near future (maximum 125 seconds for a `Stop` command).

Comment: The last statement is not necessarily accurate, if the service is "degraded" it can get stuck in a "StopPending" for hours or even days. We have unfortunately seen this happen in production under certain unexpected conditions.

Comment: Great! Thought that happens only with `Scheduled Tasks`. And what did you do? Call `Taskkill.exe` after the official 2 minutes and 5 seconds?

Comment: We used stop-process, in our case we were generally stopping all services so any services that didn't stop within our timeframe that we "owned" we could kill, otherwise you would need to find the service/process id map prior to stopping the service as depending on how far it gets they may become unlinked but the process does not stop.

Comment: I've posted an answer with the script i recently created to do this. i didn't do the full service/process mapping, but using get-ciminstance instead of get-service would make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

To add more details to my response to @Christoph

here is a script i recently created to stop services and ensure the processes are also stopped. in our case the processes were predictable. it may be necessary to do more work to get the service/processid mapping if you have multiple services running off the same executeable.

```
$MaxWait = 180 #seconds

$ServiceNames = "MyServiceName*"
$ProcName = 'MyServiceProcName' #for the services
    
$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() # to keep track of 
$WaitTS = (New-TimeSpan -Seconds $MaxServiceWait) #could also use a smaller interval if you want more progress updates
    
$InitialServiceState = get-service $ServiceNames | select Name,Status,StartType
    

    
write-Host "$ENV:COMPUTERNAME Stopping $ServiceNames"
    
$sw.Restart()
$Services = @()
$Services += Get-Service $ServiceNames | where Status -EQ Running | Stop-Service -PassThru -NoWait #nowait requires powershell 5+
$Services += Get-Service $ServiceNames | where Status -Like *Pending

#make sure the processes are actually stopped!
while (Get-Process | where Name -Match $ProcName)
{
    #if there were services still running
    if ($Services) {
        Write-Host "$ENV:COMPUTERNAME ...waiting up to $MaxServiceWait sec for $($Services.Name)"
        #wait for the service to stop
        $Services.WaitForStatus("Stopped",$WaitTS)
         
    }
    #if we've hit our maximum wait time
    if ($sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -gt $MaxServiceWait) {
        Write-Host "$ENV:COMPUTERNAME Waited long enough, killing processes!"
        Get-Process | where name -Match $ProcName | Stop-Process -Force
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    #get current service state and try and stop any that may still be running
    #its possible that another process tried to start a service while we were waiting
    $Services = @()
    $Services += Get-Service $ServiceNames | where Status -EQ Running | Stop-Service -PassThru  -NoWait #nowait requires powershell 5+
    $Services += Get-Service $ServiceNames | where Status -Like *Pending
}
```