# Wait..until in a ForEach

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario where I need to wait in a `ForEach` loop before doing a command.

```
$classList = Get-ClassList
forEach ($class in $classList) {
    $studentList = Get-StudentList -class $class.Name
    forEach ($student in $studentList) {
        Write-Host $student.Name
        $rollCall = Roll-Call -student $student.Name
    }
}
```

The thing I'm looking to solve is to wait until a student to roll. When he is already roll-called, I need to get his output (just a roll-call info), as follows:

```
$update = Get-RollCallOutput-student $student.Name -class $class.Name
```

The roll-call of each student takes may vary. Moreover, the output is a `String.Object[]` type. That said, to get specific output, I need to loop the Roll-Call Update.

```
forEach ($output in $update) {
   Get-Output -outputID $output.Id -student $student.Name
}
```

By design, if the roll-call of a student is completed, the `Get-RollCallOutput` will not return **Null**. Otherwise it is null. That said, in order to wait for the output NOT to be NULL, I used `While($job)`

```
$update = Get-RollCallOutput-student $student.Name -class $class.Name
while($job)
forEach ($output in $update) {
   Get-Output -outputID $output.Id -student $student.Name
}
```

The problem is that this one is inside nested ForEach which hangs always. Currently the workaround is to use `Start-Sleep -s 15` in order to wait for the roll-call to be done before the script jumps to query the output. I know this is not a good solution and really makes a performance impact. However, while researching better way, this would be kind of acceptable.

[**Updated**] Even use `Do ... While` but does not work. I always see it hanged after Roll-Call command.

```
Do {
   $update = Get-RollCallOutput-student $student.Name -class $class.Name
}

While ($job) {...}
```

Comment: This can be solve with a loop.
Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355759/879613

Comment: The function is just to return the collection list where I need to loop each item in the list. Again, this is just an example. The actual scenario doesn't have any service. Thank you for your response

Comment: @mklement0 as said, don't treat the example is like a Windows server and whatever a service is. Focus on the part of if I need that stuff to be fully started before retrieving it output, what would be the solution. By design if that stuff is not started, its output is null. And the only way to check the output is also reflecting back to retrieve the stuff.

Comment: That sounds like you need to keep _polling_ that stuff until its output is non-`$null`. In the abstract: `while($job) {...}` isn't even _entered_ if `$job` happens to be `$null` (or anything else that is "falsy"), so your saying that it _hangs_ implies that `$job` is _not_ `$null`. If you _do_ enter the polling loop, you need a way to _query_ the stuff in the loop body in order to determine its status (without _affecting_ its status). Only _you_ can know _if_ that's possible and _how_ - unless you tell us more.