# PowerShell different services to run in particular sequence (Remotely)

Tags: powershell, service

First post! I apologize in advance for formatting. I'm just getting familiar with PowerShell and I'm wanting to Stop a service first, restart another service, and start the initial service. Before moving onto the next next service, I want to make sure that the service has stopped before proceeding.

I'm using this function that was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186904/powershell-wait-for-service-to-be-stopped-or-started) and tried to tailor it for my code.

Workflow Goal:

1. Stop Service A
2. Restart Service B
3. Start Service A

Code:

```
#Stops Service A and validates its in "Stopped" status
Get-Service 'ServiceNameA' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerA' | Stop-Service -force -PassThru

function WaitUntilServices1($searchString, $status)
{
    # Get all services where DisplayName matches $searchString and loop through each of them.
    foreach($service in (Get-Service -DisplayName $searchString))
    {
        # Wait for the service to reach the $status or a maximum of 30 seconds
        $service.WaitForStatus($status, '00:00:30')
    }
}

WaitUntilServices1 "ServiceDisplayNameA" "Stopped"

#Restarts Service B and validates its in "Running" status
Get-Service 'ServiceNameB' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerB' | Restart-Service -force -PassThru

function WaitUntilServices2($searchString, $status)
{
    # Get all services where DisplayName matches $searchString and loop through each of them.
    foreach($service in (Get-Service -DisplayName $searchString))
    {
        # Wait for the service to reach the $status or a maximum of 30 seconds
        $service.WaitForStatus($status, '00:00:30')
    }
}

WaitUntilServices2 "ServiceDisplayNameB" "Running"

#Start Service A and validates its in "Running" status
Get-Service 'ServiceA' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerA' | Start-Service -force -PassThru

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

The Code I have above is giving me the following Errors for both of the functions.

```
Exception calling "WaitForStatus" with "2" argument(s): "Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed." At C:\PowerShell\ScriptExample\ScriptExampleFix.ps1:10 char:9
$service.WaitForStatus($status, '00:00:30')

+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TimeoutException
```

Then for the very last portion to start the service I'm getting 1 more error:

```
Start-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'force'. At C:\PowerShell\ScriptExample\ScriptExampleFix.ps1:32 char:85
+ ... erName 'ServerNameExample' | Start-Service -force -PassTh ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Service], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Any help would get greatly appreciated :)

Comment: And what's the question? Is it not working as expected? If so, please explain what behavior you're expecting and the unexpected behavior that you're actually seeing :) FWIW you don't need to define the same function twice - you can call it as many times as you like

Comment: ah sorry! updated the post with the issue. So focused on getting the formatting right that I forgot to put the issue

Comment: Well, on line two you stop a service _on a remote computer_, then you call `WaitUntilServices1` to wait on a service by the same name _on your local computer_ - which obviously won't be stopping because you never tried to stop it :)

Comment: Ah didnt catch that! So the correct way to call upon the function would be

'WaitUntilServices1 "ServiceDisplayNameA" "Stopped"  -ComputerName "ExampleServerA"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first statement:

```
#Stops Service A and validates its in "Stopped" status
Get-Service 'ServiceNameA' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerA' | Stop-Service -force -PassThru
```

You ask PowerShell to stop `ServiceNameA` *on a remote computer*.

You then call `WaitUntilServices1` which attempts to wait for a service of the same name *on your local computer* - which is obviously not gonna stop any time soon because you requested stopping *a service on a different computer*.

Change the function definition to accept a `-ComputerName` parameter too and pass that to `Get-Service`:

```
function Wait-ServiceStatus {
  param(
    [string]$Name,
    [string]$ComputerName = $('.'),
    [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]$Status
  )

  foreach($service in Get-Service -Name $Name -ComputerName $ComputerName){
    # If any call to WaitForStatus times out and throws, return $false
    try { $service.WaitForStatus($Status, '00:00:30') } catch { return $false }
  }

  # No errors thrown while waiting, all is good, return $true
  return $true
}
```

Now we can do:

```
# request the remote SCM stop the service
Get-Service 'ServiceNameA' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerA' | Stop-Service -Force

$success = Wait-ServiceStatus -Name 'ServiceNameA' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerA' -Status Stopped

if(-not $success){
  # output an error
  Write-Error "failed to complete restart cycle, 'ServiceNameA' on 'ExampleServerA' failed to stop in a timely manner"
  # return from this script/function for good measure
  return
}

# ... if we've reached this point the wait must have been successful, continue with the restart cycle.
Get-Service 'ServiceNameB' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerB' | Restart-Service -force -PassThru

$success = Wait-ServiceStatus -Name 'ServiceNameB' -ComputerName 'ExampleServerB' -Status Running
if(-not $success){
  # ... etc.
}
```

Comment: This worked! If you're willing/don't mind, can you explain the logic on how the function works? So the function passed through 'Get-Service'?

Comment: @RadCode I can try, what is it you're hoping to get a better understanding off?